# python, linux, vim, tmux: Split the python interpreter shell with tmux in order to have 1 window dedicated to variables exploration

Tags: python, linux, vim

I recently started to work on a setup where I recreate a simple python IDE using vim and tmux: I split my terminal window into 1 vim pane where I edit the code and 1 pane where I can run it using the python shell.

I was wondering if it would be possible to split the python shell into 2 panes in order to interact with the script and have at next to it a pane where I display all the variables that I am using. (I could imagine having a simple script using globals() and some autoreload of some sort to achieve that)

Does anyone knows if it is possible/how to split a python shell in such way?
Maybe have some links where this time of setup is explained? I tried to google "python tmux variable explorer" but couldn't find any post describing such setting.

Comment: Python shell is a command-line program. It has nothing to do with panes and, therefore, cannot be split.

Comment: @DYZ  ok. any suggestion on how to build a variable explorer for python? Or any pointers? (not using a graphical IDE but simply in the shell environment/context)